# Chef file evaluation only_if

Tags: chef-recipe

Attempting to File.readlines fails at converge even with 'only_if' check:

```
ruby_block 'set_archive_mode' do
  only_if (File.exists?(node['ORACLE_DATABASE']['ORACLE_ADMIN'] + '/' + 
  node['ORACLE_DATABASE']['ORACLE_SID'] + '/database_archive_verify.test'))
  if File.readlines(node['ORACLE_DATABASE']['ORACLE_ADMIN'] + '/' + 
  node['ORACLE_DATABASE']['ORACLE_SID'] + 
  '/database_archive_verify.test').grep(/^NOARCHIVELOG/).size > 0
      node.run_state['archive_mode'] = 'noarchivelog'
  else
      node.run_state['archive_mode'] = 'archivelog'
  end
end
```

The code just needs to set a node.run_state transient attribute based on the contents of the file.  I've tried several different approaches all resulting in various errors.  The above code include 'only_if', but the File.readlines is still being evaluated at converge.

Comment: For code readability you should extract path to variable, because you are using it multiple times, you should also use File.join for path. For reading file you could use `File(path).read.include? var`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ruby_block` wrong, your "readlines" code should be [put in the block attribute](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html).